# Recursive memory "tree": properly freeing memory

Tags: c++, recursion, memory, segmentation-fault, c++17

Fresh out of my first CS class, I wanted to get more practice with recursive memory allocation, so I decided to make a little game known as the "Recursive Dungeon." It simply allows users to roam through an infinite dungeon by recursively generating a new "room" every time a player enters an empty (NULL) room.

The new room is then saved, and can be accessed by...

1. Going down the exact same path that was used when entering the room
2. If you leave the room, retracing your steps back to the same room

*The program doesn't use cycles (at least, I don't think it does). I'm unfamiliar with the concept of a cycle as well as how to use it.

The problem I'm running into is when I try to clean up all the recursively-allocated memory (the "rooms"), I receive the classic error "segmentation fault: core dumped".

Below is my structure "room":

```cpp
    struct room
    {//begin struct

        room* backward;
        room* left;
        room* forward;
        room* right;

        string desc;
  
        room() { //begin
    
            backward = NULL;
            left = NULL;
            forward = NULL;
            right = NULL;
    
        /*End*/}
 
    /*End struct*/};
```

Each "room" has other rooms connected to it (left/right/forward/backward). The user starts in an empty room pointer "startingpoint", and may go in any of the above directions. Upon attempting to enter an empty (NULL) room, a new room is randomly generated for the user enter into.

Once the player is satisfied exploring, I attempt to clean up the allocated memory using an array that stores all the rooms before ending the program. Instead, it causes the segmentation fault. Here is the code:

```
    void ClearAllocatedMemory(room* aRoom, room** roomArray, int& raIndex) {

        for(short i=0; i<raIndex; i++) {//begin for
    
            delete roomArray[i];
    
        /*End for*/}
    
        delete[] roomArray;

    /*End func*/}
```

Here is the code that makes my array and defines its first (0th) index:

```
    room** roomArray;
    int raIndex = 0;

    room* startingpoint = new room();
    roomArray[0] = startingpoint;
```

And here is the code that adds in new rooms to the `roomArray` index:

```
    room* GenRoom(room** roomArray, int& raIndex) {

        room* newroom = new room();
    
        newroom->desc = GenRoomDesc( rand()%12 + 1 );
    
        raIndex++;
    
        roomArray[raIndex] = newroom;

        return newroom;


    }
```

Comment: *"comments regarding how to ... improve the clarity/formatting"* Step one: remove the empty lines from the code, they take a lot of space.

Comment: Can you ever reach a room you've already were in? Can you do so without retracing your steps (i.e. are there any cycles in the graph)?

Comment: I would imagine that `room->left->right` is just such a cycle and that is what is wrong with the code presented.

Comment: @john I mean non-trivial cycles like left->left->left->left

Comment: I think recursion and manual memory management is not the best way to do this. You should store the rooms in one data structure that allows you do efficiently perform the operations you need. I don't see why you would use recursion at all, since this problem isn't inherently recursive.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes, it is indeed possible to reach a room you have already been in. But no, the only way to do so is by retracing your steps. I'll be sure to clarify this in my post.

Comment: @BessieTheCow You're probably right, I'm new to c++ and coding in general, and there is likely a better way to tackle this sort of program without recursion.

Originally, I chose recursion to tackle this problem not because it was necessarily efficient, but because I wanted to practice recursion and recursive memory within a fun project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm would not work even if double delete was okay.
If you have two rooms connected to each other, they will recursively try to delete each other leading to stack overflow. I.e. you cannot delete cycles with simple recursion.

You have a design problem - who owns each room? Had this been written in a garbage-collected language, you would not care and the rooms would own each other simply by their own existence. In C++ you must care and the design should reflect that.

`shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` would be messy in this case. Even if you could establish an tree-like hierarchy and thus use `unique_ptr`, it can lead to stack overflow simply due to the nested destructors for deep trees.

The best and easiest solution is to create a single `std::vector<Room>` that is the clear owner of all the rooms. The neighbours can then use indices into this vector. One caveat is that deallocating rooms in the center of the vector invalidates the higher indices. This can be resolved with a swap with the last element and fixing just their connections. It would also make delete from the middle O(1).

If the map is really dynamic, as is your case, I could argue either for `std::list<Room>` - use iterators or pointers for the neighbours - or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Room>>` - use raw **non-owning** pointers.

Just a warning with these neighbour-only solutions - when a player explores rooms in a loop, you have no tools how to determine whether that room already should exist or not. E.g. going 2 up, 2 right, 2down, 2 left should return the player to the initial room. You might want to consider actually using 2D grid (and worry about memory/performance later).

Comment: 100% agree that the core problem here is that it is not clear who or what owns the rooms.

Comment: I think I see what you mean by double delete, and why it needs to be fixed- my ClearAllocatedMemory function would sometimes attempt to delete a single room twice, right?


Also, thank you for your suggestion on placing all the rooms in a single 1D vector array. It sounds like a great idea that will make things a lot more manageable. I'll try implementing it and update my post accordingly.

Comment: @Yes, it will almost surely delete it twice because the pointer to a  room is always in at least two places, apart from the map edges. Try it out :) You can also post a new question if you encounter any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm would work if your room graph where a plain tree (no going back). Since you can go back, you need to take care not to process again a room you are already processing.

I will show two ways of doing so, one is good for an arbitrary graph and the other one only for a tree with back links.

---

Method 1. The room class should have a boolean `visited` flag (not visited by the gamer, but by the deplete sequence). The initial value is `false`. Then your delete function should be modified like this:

```
ClearAllocatedMemory(room* aRoom) {
   if (aRoom == nullptr || aRoom->visited) return;
   aRoom->visited = true;
   ClearAllocatedMemory(aRoom->backward);
   ClearAllocatedMemory(aRoom->left);
   ClearAllocatedMemory(aRoom->forward);
   ClearAllocatedMemory(aRoom->right);
   delete room;
}
```

This essentially turns the deletion process into [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

---

Method 2. The room deletion routine should know what room it has been reached *from*, and not touch that room.

```
ClearAllocatedMemory(room* aRoom, room* parent) {
   if (aRoom == nullptr) return;

   if (aRoom->backward != parent)   ClearAllocatedMemory(aRoom->backward, aRoom);
   if (aRoom->left     != parent)   ClearAllocatedMemory(aRoom->left,     aRoom);
   if (aRoom->forward  != parent)   ClearAllocatedMemory(aRoom->forward,  aRoom);
   if (aRoom->right    != parent)   ClearAllocatedMemory(aRoom->right,    aRoom);

   delete room;
 }
```

This is just normal top-to-bottom tree traversal, with added checks that prevent going up.

---

The first method is probably preferable because it is universal, and you can make the deletion routine a *destructor*, as it should be in C++. But this is bor another occasion.

Note also that this check

```
if ( (aRoom->backward == NULL) && (aRoom->left == NULL)\
        && (aRoom->forward == NULL) && (aRoom->right == NULL) ) {
```

doesn't make a lot of sense. Every room needs to be deleted, not just those that do not have outgoing paths.

Answer (score 1):

Doing some more research, recalling *stack* vs *heap* memory, and reading through this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-in-c/)- I think I may have figured out the issue in the above code.

After changing how I clean up my memory, from using recursion to using an array as @Quimby suggested, I implemented a room** array to hold all the rooms. The issue I'm running into is that I'm attempting to delete the room** when it shouldn't be deleted: the room** is allocated off the **stack** instead of the **heap** since I didn't use the keyword `new` to create it.

Therefor, to fix my code, I simply need to take out the `delete[] roomArray;` from my function.